# Error message that I am creating or deleting too many events in Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am getting an error message that says I am adding or deleting too many events in too short a time in Google Calendar. I created a script that creates event blocks in our booking calendars in the same time period each day of the week, but are not connected as a series (so that users cannot accidentally overwrite other bookings in a connected series of blocks).  The most I appear to be able to create are 40 events, but sometimes not even that many. Is there a piece of code that I can add to the script that would indicate that the large number of events being created is not a mistake (the rationale for the governor, I think)?

I've found a couple strands, but because I'm new I am unable to comment or ask for clarification in other strands.

Comment: Hi. So, after a bit more  investigation I found that using the Utilities.sleep function (a relatively new addition to Google's javascript??) allows the script to execute without the error message. I just inserted the sleep method in the function after the while-loop and had the script sleep for 3 seconds. I was able to have it create 800 events without the error.

Comment: Congrats! According to Stackoverflow best practices, you should answer your own question and choose it as accepted once it allows you.