# Google Calendar API: Increase daily calendar creation quota

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are contemplating using Google Calendar as a part of the back end to a web app that my company is developing. Essentially we would be using a service account that creates and manages shared calendars that groups of users have access to.

Unlike the quotas for requests per 100 seconds and requests per day the api console does not allow the number of daily calendars to be increased.

Google specifies that 25 calendars per day can be created on an account. Given the nature of our application this limit can easily be exceeded during certain times of the fiscal year.

Is there a way to increase this quota through Google?

Source:[Google Calendar API Usage Limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en)

Comment: I think it is due to the abusive use that is why they limited the creation of calendar up to that limit. If you will encountering the error, I think the workaround from [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308656/error-you-have-been-creating-or-deleting-too-many-calendars-or-calendar-events?lq=1) and [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223732/error-message-that-i-am-creating-or-deleting-too-many-events-in-google-calendar) can help. Refer to [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473732/google-calendar-api-calendar-usage-limits-exceeded?rq=1) as reference.

Comment: Were you able to get an answer somewhere? I have a similar use case as you, and am wondering the same thing.